# How to display data form Html getting as response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using one Api which is returning html in response for one key, I want to get the data from it, I am using AngularJs how can I consume that type of response and take the desired value from it ?

Response-

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "subject": "Don’t Give Up",
  "body": "<strong>Subject: </strong>Don’t Give Up <br /><strong>From: </strong>\"Jhon Doe\"<br /><strong>To: </strong><a href=\"https://example.com/index.php/\"><span>Jhon Doe</span></a> &lt;jhon@doe.com&gt;<br /><br /><hr /><p style=\"text-align:center;\"><img src=\"https://example.com/assets/img/mylogo.png\" style=\"width:120px;\" alt=\"mylogo.png\" /></p>\n<br /><span style=\"font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;\">Hi Jhon,<br /><br />\nDon’t give up! This is the main body of the mail which I want to display how can I take that body out of here and display it in the browser  Please Help :(  </span><br /><br />\Click!\n<p style=\"text-align:center;\"><a href=\"https://somsite.com\"><img alt=\"button.png\" src=\"https://example.com/index.php\" width=\"250\" /></a> ​</p>\n started!<br /><br /><span style=\"font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;\">Thanks!<br /><br />\nJhon Doe</span><img src=\"https://example.com/index.php/\" alt=\" />",
  "firstName": "Jhon",
  "...":"...",
}
```

It's basically an email which I am getting as response I just want to display the body of that email which is starting from `Hi Jhon`. Anyone please help me how can I do that in AngularJs

Answer (score 1):

For that, you will:

- Use `$http` (or any alternative). The standard way for that is creating a service.
- It'll return a promise (so, you'll have to use `.then` and `.catch`
- Also, take into consideration the response is the whole object. So, when you try to get the body/data from the response, you will have to do `response.data`

I just created this example: https://plnkr.co/edit/FNxEeVZti6D1wmLe?preview

In your specific case you will have something like:

```
.service('EmailAPI', function($http) {
  return ({
    getEmailById: function (id) {
        return $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'YOURAPI/YOURROUTEFOREMAIL'
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        });      
    }
  })
})
```

In the controller you will have to do:

```
  EmailAPI.getEmailById('EMAILID').then(function (response) {
    $scope.email =  response.data;
  });
```

Finally, in the view, you will have to do:

```
<div>
  {{email.subject}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, so I need to fetch api like this ? but the problem here is I am working on a big project that api response is in normal json for rest of the fields, I am not sure if I can change this and also for api calling we are using jQuery way I have to work on that  particular response only :( sorry if I miss understood something..

Comment: You can also call the API with jquery in that case, not a big deal (that I mean by any alternative). The answer is taking into consideration a JSON as the response from the API. This example should work with your Project, API and jQuery (including those small changes)